# why does my image move when i hover over it

Tags: html, image, hover

So I have an image on my website inside a div with a border over it of 8px like a thumbnail so that when I click the img it links to a page. But when i hover over the image it moves (what i think to be precisely) 16px (the length of the border on both sides. Does it have anything to do with the fact the div has a border when when the image is hovered it is no longer in the div? I dont know. Some reason with explanation would be great. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="box1" class="box"><br>
   <a href="google.com"><img src="images/box1.png" /></a><br>
</div><br>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 8px solid white;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}


 img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
}
```

I've tried things like img a:hover to change things and also margin-left: -16px but that didnt work either. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you don't need <br> in css

Comment: I added that in after i pasted the code in because the preview wasnt showing it me with lines - i dont have br in css irl!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `a img:hover`, not `img a:hover`, like

```
img a:hover {
    margin-left: -16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a JSFiddle of your thing and there is now no problem with hovering. I'm not sure if it ever did hover, but your CSS is all whack. There shouldn't be random `<br>` tags in it, as `<br>` isn't a part of CSS at all. Here's your JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/PsW2S/

Comment: thanks, my css doesnt have <br> tags in it, it was just that when i wrote this in the website it didnt have any lines so i had to add them in but then it had them on this page so that was a mistake on mybehalf